# URL routing with dynamic parameters?

Tags: php, url

Currently, in my `Router` class, I have this function:

```
public function findRouteForRequestURI($uri)
{
    if(isset($this->routes[$uri])) {
        $match['class']  = $this->routes[$uri]['controller'];
        $match['action'] = $this->routes[$uri]['action'];

        if(isset($this->routes[$uri]['params'])) {
            // Not sure about this part yet
            if ($this->routes[$uri]['params']) {
                $uriSegments = explode('/', $uri);
                $match['params'] = $uriSegments;
            }
        }
        return $match;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I have this array of whitelisted routes, `$this->routes`:

```
private $routes = array(
    '/'     => array(
        'controller' => 'controllers\product\Product',
        'action'    => 'getAllProducts'
    ),
    '/cart'  => array(
        'controller' => 'controllers\cart\Cart',
        'action'     => 'getCartDetails'
    ),
    '/product/\d+/' => array( // Not sure how to do this for routes with dynamic parameters
        'controller' => 'Product',
        'action'    => 'getProductDetails',
        'params'    => true
    )
);
```

My problem is I'm not sure how I would create a whitelisted route for a URL with dynamic parameters. Say I want to have `/product/12`, where the segment `12` can be any number.

`/product/:id` would actually try to look for the controller `Product` with a method called `getProductDetails` that would accept one parameter, which is the `productId`. That is not shown here however, the searching and instantiation parts, as I have them in my `Dispatcher` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to dynamically match a route, but you'll want to keep your simpler isset in place first to avoid the overhead if possible:

```
if(!isset($this->routes[$uri])) {
    // this could also be moved to a subroutine
    // like $this->handleDynamicRoute($uri);
    $dynamicRoutes = $this->getDynamicRoutes();

    foreach ($dynamicRoutes as $route) {
        if (preg_match($route['pattern'], $uri) {
            $uriSegments     = explode('/', $uri);
            $match['params'] = (int) array_pop($uriSegments);
            $uri             = "/" . $uriSegments[0];
        }
    }
}

// proceed as before...
$match['class']  = $this->routes[$uri]['controller'];
$match['action'] = $this->routes[$uri]['action'];
```

We have this little number to sort out all the routes that have a regex pattern. There's probably a more efficient way to do this:

```
private function getDynamicRoutes()
{
    $dynamicRoutes = [];
    foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
        if (isset($route['pattern'])) {
            $dynamicRoutes[] = $route;
        }
    }
    return $dynamicRoutes;
}
```

In concert with this you could keep your routes array a little cleaner:

```
'/product' => [
    'controller' => 'Product',
    'action'     => 'getProductDetails',
    'pattern'    => '/product/\d+/'
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one question though, why did you set `$uri` at the end? Set it with `"/" . $uriSegments[0];`

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clearer - it was so that you could still retrieve the action and the controller from the array as before. Glad I could help!  I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer.